# Using AWK to select rows with specific value in specific column

Tags: linux, shell, awk, csv

I have a big csv file, which looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
1,2,3,4,5,6,25178
1,2,3,4,5,6,27986
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
```

I want to select only the lines in which the 7th columns is equal to -99, so my output be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
1,2,3,4,5,6,-99
```

I tried the following:

```
awk -F, '$7 == -99' input.txt > output.txt
awk -F, '{ if ($7 == -99) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }' input.txt > output.txt
```

But both of them returned an empty output.txt. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: the first command works for me, second has a minor typo (closing parenthesis in print stmt) and doesn't set OFS... what is your awk version? probably you have dos style line endings? (but that doesn't cause an issue when I checked)

Comment: How do I know my awk version? Yes, I typed it wrong in here, but it's correct in my script.

Comment: With old `awk` you could try `awk -F, '$7 == "-99"'`.

Comment: for version, try the command `awk --version` if that doesn't work, check `man awk`

Comment: My version is 1.2

Comment: These have also returned an empty output.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file that you run the script on has DOS line-endings.  It may be that it was created on a Windows machine.

Use `dos2unix` to convert it to a Unix text file.

Alternatively, run it through `tr`:

```
tr -d '\r' <input.txt >input-unix.txt
```

Then use `input-unix.txt` with your otherwise correct `awk` code.

---

To modify the `awk` code instead of the input file:

```
awk -F, '$7 == "-99\r"' input.txt >output.txt
```

This takes the carriage-return at the end of the line into account.

Or,

```
awk -F, '$7 + 0 == -99' input.txt >output.txt
```

This forces the 7th column to be interpreted as a number, which "removes" the carriage-return.

Similarly,

```
awk -F, 'int($7) == -99' input.txt >output.txt
```

would also remove the `\r`.

Comment: I tried the "-99\r" and it worked! That was it. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

```
awk -F, '{if($7==-99)print $0}'
```

will do that...

Comment: As would `awk -F, '$7 == -99' input.txt` (from the question), which means that there's something else going on than just getting the `awk` code right.

Comment: Empty output...

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F',' '$7 ~ /-99/ {print $0}' filename.csv > result.csv
```

1. Please note that `','` defines your separator to be comma.
2. `$` defines column. 
   so, `$7` defines the column number which you want to have a special value. here `7`.
3. `~ /-99/` searches for `-99`. you might put anything you need.
4. `$0` stands for ALL the columns in the file. You could simply write `$1","$2","......`if you do not want to print only specific columns.(or `$1$2...` if you do not need comma as separator for your results)
5. `> result.csv` saves the output instead of printing it in terminal in `result.scv` file.

Comment: Note that [Wayne’s approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557439/86440) is simpler still, so this isn’t the simplest solution ;-).

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining the command for an `awk` noob like me :-)

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to @tonioc's answer

```
awk '{if($7 == -99){print}}' file > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

a little late to the party.. but this should do it

`awk -F, '$7 ~ /-99/' input.txt > output.txt`

your original would also work if you added quotes, like so

`awk -F, '$7 == "-99"' input.txt > output.txt`

The default action when using a pattern match is to print, so `{print}` wont be needed